# Weird thread behaviour in linux kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm learning to code linux kernel modules and I recently stumbled on an error with this code radiatorpalacesummitseaweed.info/main.txt

Initially, if Section B is commented, the function `tthread()` does not see the value of `x` as 10, rather some junk. However, if Section B is un-commented, `tthread()` sees the value of `x` as 10 but `dthread()` doesn't.

I did some research and created up to 7 threads and it always seems that the last thread to be created does not see the changed `x`.

Any idea why this is a problem?

EDIT: I'm running on kernel v2.6.22.14 32 bits.